# Does Internet Explorer "show pictures" option not show pictures or not downloading them?

Tags: internet-explorer

Does anybody know if the **"Show pictures"** option under **IE>Internet Options>Advanced Tab>Setting>Multimedia**, stops the browser from **showing pictures** or stops it from **downloading pictures**?

Comment: I don't "know" this, but logic impels me to believe that they are not downloaded, just for bandwidth purposes.

Comment: @Xavierjazz thanks, Yes I thought so, that's why I asked to be sure.

Comment: If you want to be extra sure on your own, fire up Wireshark and/or Fiddler and examine you HTTP/network traffic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is specifically designed for slow connections and slow devices. It prevents browser from downloading pictures.

- [source 1](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/guests/pictures)
- [source 2](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/turn-off-images-internet-explorer-14601.html)
- [source 3](http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=11644)

Also from Internet Explorer Help chapter:

> Turn off multimedia in Internet Explorer. By default, Internet Explorer
>   displays multimedia (such as pictures, videos, or sounds) used on
>   webpages. You can turn off multimedia if you want to **increase the
>   speed at which the page loads** or if you use a screen reader.

Comment: so its actually for both **slow systems** (to load less graphical contents) and **slow connections** (to load less data). thanks